# How to animate view height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

**The goal**
I’d like to be able to animate the height of two views stacked on top of each other in a column. Three situations can occur:

- The top view covers all of the available space, and therefore the
  bottom view becomes invisible.
- The bottom view covers all of the available space, and therefore the top view becomes invisible.
- Both views are visible. If the top view takes let's say 30%, the bottom view should take the other 70% of the total available height.

**The problem**
Things work fine if I animate the height of the top view between about 20% and 80%. The animation is exactly what I want; one view grows and the other one shrinks in height, while the width of both views stay the same.

[image]

However, if I animate the height of the top view between 0% and 100% things get weird:

[image]

I guess this behaviour can be explained because in the end situation both the height and the width of the pushed out view are 0. Note that I’m using a ConstraintLayout, but there is no requirement for that. Just thought that would be the most easy thing to do. I've tried not animating the top view but a guideline in the middle, but that didn't work either.

**Bonus question**
What would be the best way to deal with the margin between those 2 views if either one of them becomes 100% visible? Of course, in the end there shouldn't be a double margin between the view and the parent (or none at all).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var cnt = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main_container)

        fixedRateTimer(
            period = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3)
        ) {
            val percentage = when (cnt++) {
                0 -> 0.0f
                2 -> 1.0f
                else -> 0.5f
            }

            root.post {
                val newConstraintSet = ConstraintSet().apply { clone(root) }
                newConstraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(R.id.top, percentage)
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root)
                newConstraintSet.applyTo(root)
            }

            if (cnt > 3) cnt = 0
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="#ff0"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#f0f"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest migrating from constraintlayout to motionlayout (which is an extension of the former) and you'll be able to easily transition between two constraint sets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but wouldn't that create the same issue? In the example I've posted I'm already transitioning between constraint sets.

Comment: I mean you're only animating percent height of top view. With ML you could alter scenes for percentages that give you trouble:. at 0 or 100% there'd be no vertical chain and you can set margin to whichever view remains visible. Also you will be able to use motion layout editor straight from studio so you'd be see animation immediately without need of build & install.

Comment: I'd really like to learn about MotionLayout so I gave it a try. I got as far as animating between 0% and 100% but I'm unsure how to continue. For example, how can I remove the margin when reaching an extend? Can you point me to some documentation? Thanks again.

Comment: Just set layout margins to 0 in bottom view constraintset of your end scene and they should be respected and animated